# How to reset draggable and droppable function on click jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to reset **draggable** function by on click using the code below.

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    alert( "dropped" );
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/Shahadat321/pen/PVjJOW

Comment: Please provide more detail to the issue. What should be clicked, a button? Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Twisty Sharing the codepen url: https://codepen.io/Shahadat321/pen/PVjJOW

Comment: The CodePen does include a more complete example, yet your description of the issue is missing. What is the expected outcome? What have you tried?